# How to identify OS in VB.Net using build number

Tags: vb.net, windows

I have an existing application that uses  System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major to identify the operating system the application is running on. I use this to make sure the application is not being run on an unsupported operating system.

I have currently hit a snag in that I need to be able to identify if the user is using Vista with no SP, Vista SP1, Vista SP2, Windows 7, Windows 7 SP1, Server 2008, Server 2008 R2, Windows 8 and Windows 8 SP1 as some settings in the application depend upon the Service Pack Version.

From what I have looked up Windows 7 and server 2008 share the same build numbers so this is a problem likewise the way Microsoft did version numbering on the minor would cause my current code to not work as expected.

Build numbers

```
Vista                       6.0.6000 
Vista SP1 ????????          6.0.6001.18000
Vista SP2                   6.0.6002
Windows Server 2008         6.0.6001
Windows 7                   6.1.7600
Windows 7 SP1               6.1.7601
Windows Server 2008 R2      6.1.7600
Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 ???  6.0.7601
```

Is their a better way to do this or an extended functionality to the System.Environment.Version to use the build number? I have spent hours searching for answers to no avail.

My current code is below

```
  Select Case System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major
        Case 5
            Select Case _
                System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor
                Case 0
                    Dim frm As New Win2000
                    frm.Show(Win2000)
                Case 1
                    Dim frm As New XP
                    frm.Show(XP)
                Case 2
                    Dim frm As New Win2003
                    frm.Show(Win2003)
                Case Else
                    Dim frm As New Unsupported
                    frm.Show(Unsupported)
            End Select
        Case 6
            Select Case _
                System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Minor
                Case 0
                    If My.Computer.Info.OSFullName.Contains("Home Basic") Then
                        Dim frm As New VistaHB
                        frm.Show(VistaHB)
                    End If
                    If My.Computer.Info.OSFullName.Contains("Home Premium") Then

                        Dim frm As New VistaPre
                        frm.Show(VistaPre)
                    End If
                    If My.Computer.Info.OSFullName.Contains("Ultimate") Then

                        Dim frm As New VistaUlt
                        frm.Show(VistaUlt)
                    End If
                    If My.Computer.Info.OSFullName.Contains("Business") Then
                        Dim frm As New VistaB
                        frm.Show(VistaB)
                    End If
                Case 1
                    If My.Computer.Info.OSFullName.Contains("Home Basic") Then
                        Dim frm As New Win7HB
                        frm.Show(Win7HB)
                    End If
                    If My.Computer.Info.OSFullName.Contains("Home Premium") Then

                        Dim frm As New Win7Pre
                        frm.Show(Win7Pre)
                    End If
                    If My.Computer.Info.OSFullName.Contains("Ultimate") Then

                        Dim frm As New Win7Ult
                        frm.Show(Win7Ult)
                    End If
                    If My.Computer.Info.OSFullName.Contains("Business") Then
                        Dim frm As New Win7biz
                        frm.Show(Win7biz)
                    End If

                Case Else
                    Dim frm As New Unsupported
                    frm.Show(Unsupported)
            End Select
    End Select
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the link below to assist me with trying to figure out the very same thing once upon a time.

http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_get_os_name.html

Taken from link above:

> WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation) lets you use SQL-like
>   statements to ask the computer about itself. This example uses it to
>   get:
>
> •The operating system name including its edition (Home, Ultimate,
>   etc.), version, and Service Pack number  •The number of logical
>   processors  •The number of bits the system uses (32 or 64)
>
> When the program loads, the following code displays these values in
>   labels.
>
> ```
>  ' Display the operating system's name. Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal _
> e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
> ' Get the OS information.
> ' For more information from this query, see:
> '      http:'msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa394239.aspx
> Dim os_query As String = "SELECT * FROM " & _
>     "Win32_OperatingSystem"
> Dim os_searcher As New _
>     ManagementObjectSearcher(os_query)
> For Each info As ManagementObject In os_searcher.Get()
>     lblCaption.Text = _
>         info.Properties("Caption").Value.ToString().Trim()
>     lblVersion.Text = "Version " & _
>         info.Properties("Version").Value.ToString() & _
>         " SP " & _
>         info.Properties("ServicePackMajorVersion").Value.ToString() _
>             & "." & _
>     info.Properties("ServicePackMinorVersion").Value.ToString()
> Next info
>
> ' Get number of processors.
> ' For more information from this query, see:
> '      http:'msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa394373.aspx
> Dim cpus_query As String = "SELECT * FROM " & _
>     "Win32_ComputerSystem"
> Dim cpus_searcher As New _
>     ManagementObjectSearcher(cpus_query)
> For Each info As ManagementObject In cpus_searcher.Get()
>     lblCpus.Text = _
>         info.Properties("NumberOfLogicalProcessors").Value.ToString() _
>             & _
>         " processors"
> Next info
>
> ' Get 32- versus 64-bit.
> ' For more information from this query, see:
> '      http:'msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa394373.aspx
> Dim proc_query As String = "SELECT * FROM " & _
>     "Win32_Processor"
> Dim proc_searcher As New _
>     ManagementObjectSearcher(proc_query)
> For Each info As ManagementObject In proc_searcher.Get()
>     lblBits.Text = _
>         info.Properties("AddressWidth").Value.ToString() _
>         & "-bit"
> Next info End Sub
>
>  The code uses the WMI query "SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem" to get information about the operating system. The result is a
> ```
>
> collection holding one Win32_OperatingSystem object. The code uses a
>   loop to get that object and reads its properties. The Caption property
>   gives the full operating system name including trademark symbols and
>   the edition. Version returns the operating system's version. The
>   ServicePackMajorVersion and ServicePackMinorVersion properties give
>   the service pack information.
>
> Next the program executes the query "SELECT * FROM
>   Win32_ComputerSystem" in a similar fashion to get the number of
>   logical processors.
>
> It finishes by executing the query "SELECT * FROM Win32_Processor" to
>   determine whether this is a 32-bit or 64-bit operating system.
>
> Note that using WMI requires that you add a reference to
>   System.Management.